# Arithmetic shift distributivity

Tags: bit-shift, xor

What are the rules if I have:

```
c = a xor (a>>b)
```

And I know c and b but not a. How could I rewrite this in order to solve?

Comment: If you have some simple equation like `c = b + a` and you know `c` and `b`, then you could rearrange the equation to `a = c - b` to get `a`. It's really the same thing here, you have have to look at it as a normal equation, and get `a` alone on one side of the `=`.

Comment: Also, is `^` supposed to be a "power" operator, or a C-like exclusive-or? The tags says `xor` but it's better to be explicit since many beginners in C-like languages mistakes `^` for a "power" operator. And there's no language tag to say that this is C-like operators.

Comment: Edited for clarity. I still don't understand how to move the arithmetic shift though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, we can't just rewrite the equation as originally suggested but we can solve it rather easily: we know that left shit just adds 0. Example if a = 123 and b = 3:

```
a = 0b1111011
a >> 3 = 0b1111011000
```

Now let's assume we only have `c` and `b` and we're trying to solve the equation as posed in the original question. We say

```
b = 3
c = 2889 = 0b101101001001
```

We know that our operation will do this:

```
a^a000 = 0b101101001001 (1)
```

Since `xor` is reversible, we can rewrite (1):

```
a = 0b101101001001^a000
```

Now since it bitwise, this already gives us the last 3 digits of a:

```
a[-3:] = 001^000 = 001 (2)
```

Now our equation (1) becomes since the last 3 binary digits of `a` are the 6th to 3rd last digits of `a << 3`:

```
a[:-3]001^a[:-3]001000 = 0b101101001001
```

Again we repeat the step in (2) until we get a:

```
a[-6:] = 001001^001000 = 000001


a[-9:] = 101001001^000001000 = 101000001
```

Et voila, we get the original `a = 0b101000001 = 123`